# popular fd/canon ae-1 lenses/acessories

Tags: lens, canon, film

I'm giving serious consideration to switching from primarily shooting film with a Pentax K1000 to a Canon AE-1 (and/or AE-1 Program).  Is anyone familiar with the model?  What are the popular fd lenses/accessories?

Answer (score 5):

The Canon AE-1 and AE-1 Program are fine models that can be acquired quite cheaply today, although I do prefer the A-1 because it has Aperture Priority which I favor instead of Shutter Priority.

FD lenses are availabe everywhere, but do look out for the newer FD lenses that don't have the mounting ring like the older ones, they are not as swiftly mounted. I found the combination of a 50 F/1.4, a 28 F/2.8 and a 135 F/2.8 to suit my needs. Look out for the SC or SSC marks in the lenses, they signify later models with better coatings that can make all the difference in the world.

Batteries (the 4LR44) are also still plenty available, in contrast to some of the other manufacturer's models of that era.